# Port botbuilder restify listener to sailsjs route

Tags: sails.js, botframework

I'm following the botbuilder demos here - https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/demo-skype/app.js

```
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
  console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

// Create chat bot
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
  appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
  appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
```

I want to host this bot inside SailsJS.
I've routed the call as follows:

```
// config/routes.js
'POST /api/messages': {
  controller: 'BotframeworkController',    
  action: 'listen',
},
```

And the controller:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var botconfig = sails.config.botframework;

var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
   appId: botconfig.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
   appPassword: botconfig.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot( connector, function( session ) {
  session.send("%s, I heard: %s", session.userData.name, session.message.text);
});

// Add help dialog
bot.dialog('help', function (session) {
  session.send("I'm a simple echo bot.");
}).triggerAction({ matches: /^help/i });

module.exports = {

  listen: function( req, res, next ){
    sails.log.debug('BotframeworkController.listen... started');
    sails.log.debug(req.body);
    return connector.listen( req, res );
    // var test = connector.listen( req, res );
    // sails.log.debug(test );
  },
}
```

I don't get any errors - that I can see - but there is no response returned to the client.

Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with `SailsJS` but it looks like it would call the `listen` method of `BotframeworkController` upon receiving a POST to `/api/messages`. Am I reading it right?

The `connector.listen()` itself is not the handler, it's the path to the handler. It returns a function that will handle the incoming request and response. Try it like this instead:

```
module.exports = {
  listen: connector.listen()
}
```